# Kotlin/Android app using Retrofit2. JSON query not working as I expect

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

Working on a small android app to help me learn about JSON queries. The little test app works until I try to drill a little deeper in to my test JSON data.

I'll post a link to the JSON data I'm working with to save space here in the question. It is example code pulled from weatherwunderground's API and hosted on myjson.com.

**JSON:** https://api.myjson.com/bins/19uurt

**MAIN ACTIVITY CODE**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val retriever = CycloneRetriever()

    val callback = object : Callback<Cyclones> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cyclones>?, response: Response<Cyclones>?) {
            println("Got a response!")
            println(response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(1)?.stormInfo?.get(0)?.stormName).toString()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Cyclones>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println("The thing, it failed!")
        }
    }
    retriever.getCyclones(callback)
}
```

}

This is my class that helps build/gather the JSON data

**CLASS**

```
interface WeatherWunderGroundAPI {
@GET("bins/19uurt")

weatherwunderground.com API
fun getCyclones() : Call<Cyclones>
}

class Cyclones(val currenthurricane: List<CurrentHurricane>)
class CurrentHurricane(val stormInfo: List<StormInfo>)
class StormInfo(val stormName: String)


class CycloneRetriever {
    val apiRetriever: WeatherWunderGroundAPI

    init {
        val retrofitCyclone = 
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    apiRetriever =retrofitCyclone.create(WeatherWunderGroundAPI::class.java)
}

fun getCyclones(callback: Callback<Cyclones>) {
    val call = apiRetriever.getCyclones()
    call.enqueue(callback)
}
```

}

Right now I'm just trying to get a good response and print that to the console. Eventually, I will take the JSON data and dump it into a RecyclerView.

I can get a good response if I do the following Println, but it does not return anything of use:

```
println(response?.body()?.currenthurricane
```

But once I try to dig further into .currenthurricane, onFailure() is called.

According to some JSON docs, this should get me what I want: `$.currenthurricane.[stormInfo].stormName` As an example.

But I cannot figure out how to get this working in my code. I was gonna give Klaxxon a try, but have not quite figured out how to get that working either.

I'm using Retrofit2 and GSON plugins in the code above. I'm fairly confident the issue is my JSON query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem. I was on the right track, but needed a little tweaking on my JSON queries and need to change my classes.

I'm still working on it, and I'm sure there is a much better way to do this, but here is the quick and dirty.

Changed my classes and added a couple data classes:

```
class Cyclones(val currenthurricane: List<CurrentHurricane>)
class CurrentHurricane(val stormInfo: StormInfo, val Current: Current)

data class StormInfo(val stormName: String)
data class Current(val lat: Double, val lon: Double, val 
SaffirSimpsonCategory: Int, val Category: String, val WindSpeed: WindSpeed, 
val Movement: Movement)

data class WindSpeed(val Kts: Int, val Mph: Int, val Kph: Int)
data class Movement(val kts: Int, val mph: Int, val kph: Int)
```

And changed my JSON queries to the following:

```
val cycloneInfo = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.stormInfo?.stormName
val cycloneCurrentLat = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.lat
val cycloneCurrentLon = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.lon
val cycloneCurrentSSCat = 
  response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.SaffirSimpsonCategory
val cycloneCurrentCategory = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.Category
val cycloneCurrentWindKts = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.WindSpeed?.Kts
val cycloneCurrentMovement = 
    response?.body()?.currenthurricane?.get(0)?.Current?.Movement?.kts
```